# Is NHibernate SysCache Absolute or Sliding

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I think the question says it all, but I'd like to know for sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the Configuration you're using (the cache policy, to be specific). The default is sliding.

Comment: Could you provide me the documentation or an example?